# How to dynamically set different Condition in Config.prop on server side in JAVA ?

Tags: java, spring

Basically i want to read differnet key values pair(url's) for different user dynamically.Means if user is 1 then the specfic urls should be shown .let's say first 10 values.and same goes for the other user's.This is my config.prop file.I want to set the values dynamically ?

User 1  (This is from the database) same applies to user 2 and user 3

KPI_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

ONTIME_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

ALERTING_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

User 2

different sets or url's 
...

same goes for user 3 and user 4.

How can i do this in config.prop file.I know how to read the values.Just i want to call the values (or key value pair) dynamically from the config.prop file.and one thing if user is 2 then only those specfic values should come.

can anybody help me in how to achieve this?? in java

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite an unusual design to have individual user-specific configuration in a properties file like this.

It might be better to have a new database attribute for users that indicates the type of config they should be given e.g. `config_type`. Let's say for example that this type would be an enum with the following made up values: REGULAR, ADVANCED, TYPE_A, TYPE_B

Then you could easily prefix the configuration with these types when fetching properties and have different values in the config file:

REGULAR_KPI_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

REGULAR_ONTIME_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

REGULAR_ALERTING_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

TYPE_A_KPI_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

TYPE_A_ONTIME_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

TYPE_A_ALERTING_TT_Executive=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.com

## etc. for other types.

This is tidier and also means you don't have to duplicate configuration in future when more than one user exists that requires the same configuration.

Personally, I would probably put user config this specific into the DB but if you have to change it regularly then I can sympathise with config files.

Comment: let's say user 1 exist in the database and user 2 also exist in the database. can i match or compare this.eg if user1=="some name" then show these url's or can i use contains? meaning if user1 contains(db value) then show these url's .how can i do this?